# On beanstalk -Cognito stops authenticating after some time and throws error of "missing credentials in config"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

First I have searched solutions, but I am unable to pinpoint the issue.

This is app hosted on beanstalk and works as intended after deploying. I can login, do what i need to do and close the app. If the browser is refreshed you will have to log in again (as intended).

**Issue:** I deployed my app around 12pm and around 2pm I tried logging in and I get a "missing credentials in config" error.

I deployed again around 2:20pm and as of now (2:58pm) it is still working as intended. But if this throws same error again, what am I possibly doing wrong?

Please see below snippet of code for my authenticating route in node js. This is a beanstalk reactjs node app.

```js
AWS.config.update({
  region: process.env.Region
});

var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

const poolData = { //--Moved to env variables
  UserPoolId: process.env.UserPoolId, // your user pool id here
  ClientId: process.env.ClientId // your app client id here
};
const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);


router.post('/api/authenticateuser', (req, res) => {

  var authenticationData = {
    Username: val.value.user, // your username here
    Password: val.value.pass, // your password here
  };
  // AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  //     IdentityPoolId: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
  // });


  const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
  var loginParams = {
    AuthFlow: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
    /* required */
    ClientId: process.env.ClientId,
    /* required */
    AuthParameters: {
      'USERNAME': val.value.user,
      'PASSWORD': val.value.pass
    }
  };
  cognitoidentityserviceprovider.initiateAuth(loginParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      // console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      res.json(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data); // successful response
      if (data.ChallengeName === process.env.Challenge_NEW_PASS) {
        res.json({
          changePass: "changePass",
          session: data.Session
        });
      } else if (data.ChallengeName === process.env.Challenge_MFA) {
        // console.log(data);
        res.json({
          MFA: "MFA",
          session: data.Session,
          user: val.value.user
        });
      } else {

        const accessToken = data.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken;
        // Add the User's Id Token to the Cognito credentials login map.
        const idToken = data.AuthenticationResult.IdToken;
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
          IdentityPoolId: process.env.IdentityPoolId,
          Logins: {
            [process.env.CognitoIdp]: idToken
          },
          LoginId: val.value.user
        });
        res.json({
          accessToken,
          idToken,
          user: val.value.user,
          test: data
        });
      }
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Cognito session expires after 1 hour by default. Your temporary access key and secret expires along with it and so does the identity token and session token. You will have to use the refresh token every hour to get new credentials. If you want to avoid this, you can try using [Amplify Authentication](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication), which will automatically do the refreshing for you.

Comment: I get this error when attempting login to get credentials

Comment: Are you using identity token to get temporary access key and secret key, or are you using username and password to get brand new tokens?

Comment: I am using username and password to get brand new tokens to intiate the login and login to app. Then after that I am using the idtoken to set the aws.config.credentials and then I get the temporary credentials to pass to s3 put bject. But the error I am getting comes on the initial login.